# Overlaying "collapsable" bullet points in LaTeX-Beamer

Tags: overlays, beamer

I am using LaTeX with Beamer to create a presentation.  I know what I want a certain slide to look like but have not been able to get it to work without the text or pictures wiggling.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Here's my idea for the slide:

On the first slide, I want the first bullet point and two sub-points displayed.  No problem.  On the second slide, I want to remove the two sub-points from the first slide, keep the main bullet
   point from the first slide in the same location, add a second main
   bullet point and three sub-points for it.  And repeat.  At the bottom
   of the slide, I want to have a picture remain in the same spot for
   all the overlays.

---Slide 1---

- First point

  - Sub point
  - Sub point

---Slide 2---

- First Point
- Second Point

  - Sub point
  - Sub point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `overlayarea` command (thanks to [this post here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30771/18674)) may be what you are searching for:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{7em}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item First Point
            \only<1>{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item subpoint
                    \item subpoint
                \end{itemize}
                }
            \uncover<2>{
                \item Second Point
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item subpoint
                    \item subpoint
                    \item another subpoint
                \end{itemize}
                }
        \end{itemize}
    \end{overlayarea}
    \rule{\linewidth}{1em} %Add your image here
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You will just have to adjust the second argument of the `\begin{overlayarea}` command to fit the height of your itemize and replace the `\rule` command with your `\includegraphics`.